# EJB  - external lib or inside JSF project?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm packaging my app as WAR archive. What are pros/cons of these two approaches:

1. Keep EJB (beans, entities etc) as separate project and include into WAR as lib (*.jar file - WEB-INF/lib) during build?
2. Keep everything (ejb-s, jsf beans etc) in one project, so after build all would go to WEB_INF/classes

Is there any performance/security difference?
I'm using GlassFish 3.1.1 WebProfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no performance/security difference for JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` versus classes in `/WEB-INF/classes`. They end up in the same context and classloader anyway. Perhaps extracting the JAR and loading its classes into memory needs a few milliseconds more, but that's totally negligible.

Only maintainability and reusability is different here. When you put EJBs in a separate project, then you can more easily reuse them for other WARs and purposes without the need to copypaste classes.